# Find maps memory and files descriptor to self process

Tags: c, linux, mmap, file-descriptor

In Linux using C, in the context of process. How can I get all address of maps memory and open files descriptor for specific kernel module that loaded into `/dev/yoyo`?

In shell script (or with `popen` ) I can use:  `ls -la /proc/self/fd | grep /dev/yoyo` to get all files descriptor  and `cat /proc/self/maps  | grep /dev/yoyo` to get all maps memories.

But how can I get than only with C code (without pipes or shell script) ?is there any functions that give me that information?

Comment: `ls` can be implemented using `opendir`, `readdir`, `readlink`, etc. Instead of `cat /proc/self/maps` you can directly open the file and read it using `fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r")`, `fgets`, etc. Note: You rarely need `cat`. Instead of `cat /proc/self/maps  | grep /dev/yoyo` use `grep /dev/yoyo /proc/self/maps`

Comment: @Bobo there is no simple function that get that information instead running in loop ?

Comment: Do you think I would suggest a complicated solution if I knew an easier one?

Comment: If the C program is process X (e.g. 37) then `cat /proc/self/maps` refers to the process for `cat` and _not_ X. We would need: `cat /proc/37/maps` to get the map for X. Almost all necessary data can be gotten from reading `/proc/whatever` directly from X without the need to call external programs.